# Diccionario donde la key es la primera cadena de una lista y la clave es otro diccionario poniendo cuantas veces aparece cada letra

Tags: python

```
def finalCounting(s):
    if len(s) == 0:
        return {}
    else:
        result = {}
        finalresult = {}
        for c in s:
            for j in c:
                if j in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
                    if result.has_key:
                        result[j] += 1
                    else:
                        result[j] += 1
            finalresult[c] = result
        return finalresult
```

Me dice que es erróneo y que hay un keyerror con la h. Un ejemplo del uso de la función seria:

`finalCounting(["hello", "bye how are you"])`

y devolveria:

```
{'bye': {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'e': 2, 'h': 1, 'o': 2, 'r': 1, 'u': 1, 'w': 1, 'y': 2}, 'hello': {'h': 1, 'e': 1, 'l': 2, 'o': 1}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes algunos errores en el código.

Primero, el método `dict.has_key(clave)` es poco pythónico, y se prefiere usar en cambio `clave in dict`. De hecho la sintaxis con `.has_key()` ha desaparecido en Python3. En todo caso, en tu código no llamabas realmente a la función pues habías puesto sólo `result.has_key`, sin invocarla ni pasarle parámetro.

Segundo, tanto si encontrabas la key como si no, hacías lo mismo, incrementar `result[j]`, por lo que si la key no estaba tendrías un error al tratar de incrementar el valor asociado. En el caso en que no esté debes *asignar* uno, en vez de incrementarlo.

Tercero, el diccionario `result` debe ser reiniciado para cada nueva "frase" (cada nuevo valor de tu variable `c``). De lo contrario estarías mezclando letras de diferentes frases.

Por último, cuando asignas `finalresult[c]`, estás usando como clave `c` que es la frase completa, cuando de acuerdo a las especificaciones deberías usar sólo la primera palabra de la frase.

Corrigiendo estos problemas, y sin entrar a valorar el resto del código:

```
def finalCounting(s):
    if len(s) == 0:
        return {}
    else:
        finalresult = {}
        for c in s:
            result = {}
            for j in c:
                if j in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
                    if j in result:
                        result[j] += 1
                    else:
                        result[j] = 1
            primera = c.split()[0]
            finalresult[primera] = result
        return finalresult
```

Que funciona correctamente:

```
finalCounting(["hello", "bye how are you"])
```

---

```
{'bye': {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'e': 2, 'h': 1, 'o': 2, 'r': 1, 'u': 1, 'w': 1, 'y': 2},
 'hello': {'e': 1, 'h': 1, 'l': 2, 'o': 1}}
```

Comment: Estoy planteando en Meta que todas las preguntas de Python muestren una sugerencia para que los usuarios etiqueten de forma más preciso. ¿Podrías darle un vistazo? [¿Podemos añadir una advertencia en las preguntas con etiqueta \[python*\]?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3860/83). Tu opinión sería interesante pues eres de los más reputados en esta etiqueta. ¡Gracias!